# Group and count on related model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table called `item` that has a belongsTo relationship with a table called `source`. I want to group all items by their source and in the end I want an array that has `source->name` as the key and number of related items as the value.

This is what I've got so far:

```
Item::where('type', '=', Item::TYPE_POST)
  ->with('source')
  ->select('source_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
  ->groupBy('source_id')
  ->pluck('total', 'source_id')
  ->all();
```

```
array:1 [
  89 => 149
]
```

This gives me the structure that I want, but the items aren't grouped by `source->name` but by `source_id` which is a field in the `Item` table. Is there a way to get the key in the array to be a field from the related table?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried these but it should get you close anyways

Using Collections

```
Item::where('type', '=', Item::TYPE_POST)
    ->with('source.name')
    ->get()
    ->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
        return [$item->service->name => $item];
    })
    ->map(function ($items, $name) {
        return [
            $name => $items->count()
        ];
    });
```

Using Query

```
DB::table('items')
    ->selectRaw('sources.name as name, count(*.items) as count')
    ->join('sources', 'sources.id', 'items.source_id')
    ->where('type', '=', Item::TYPE_POST)
    ->groupBy('sources.id')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('count', 'name')
```